# How to discourage a page break without completely prohibiting it in a block of formulas?

Tags: align, page-breaking, mathtools, penalty, displaybreak

Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\predisplaypenalty=0%%% that's what our class svmono.cls from a nonminimal example (not given here) does.
\usepackage[helvratio=.9]{newtxtext}
\usepackage[slantedGreek,subscriptcorrection]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{mathic=true}
\begin{document}
Begin.\\[101.9ex]%%% with 101.8ex, the f-block is on p.1.  With 101.9ex, the f-block is on p.2
Consider the following functions:
\begin{align*}
  f\colon \mathbb{N}&\to \mathbb{N}\\% allow for a page break after : ℕ → ℕ under a penalty
  0&\mapsto 0\\
  1&\mapsto 1\\
  \vdots\displaybreak[0]\\
  g\colon \mathbb{N}&\to \mathbb{N}\\% allow for a page break after : ℕ → ℕ under a penalty
  0&\mapsto 1\\
  1&\mapsto 2\\
  \vdots
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

to pdflatex yields

[image: output]

We'd like to *unwillingly* allow for page breaks after “: ℕ → ℕ” and “: ℕ → ℕ”, i.e., with a positive penalty; in other words, let a page break occur there iff there's too much vertical space left on page 1 otherwise. In particular, these breaks should be neither fully prohibited nor unconditionally allowed for.  Unfortunately, `\displaybreak[]` seems to have no effect for negative  (and the documentation mentions only nonnegative values between 0 and 4 anyway).  What to do?

In other words, we need three kinds of line breaks in the scope of the `align*` environment:

A. one completely prohibiting a page break,

B. one unwillingly allowing a page break, and

C. one allowing a page break (without additionally encouraging or discouraging it compared to, say, `\displaybreak[0]\\` or to `\allowdisplaybreaks` followed by `\\`).

I plan to place the line breaks of type A after “0 ↦ 0” and “0 ↦ 1”, the line breaks of type B after “: ℕ → ℕ” and “: ℕ → ℕ”, and the line break of type C after “⋮”.

Comment: According to the `amsmath` user guide, "When display breaks are enabled with `\allowdisplaybreaks`, the `\\*` command can be used to prohibit a pagebreak after a given line, as usual."

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes. We don't wish to prohibit a page break, but we wish to make it less likely in comparison to possible page breaks before/after the `align*` environment and to a page break between the first vertical ellipsis “⋮” and “: ℕ → ℕ”.

Comment: A page break before a display block is considered bad style by recognized math style guides.  In your code you have overridden that.  The choice to allow a break after the vertical ellipsis is good, but applying the recommended `\\*` instead of your attempted `\displaybreak[0]` should be more reliable.  (It simply allows, not insists on, a break.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks! What's the point of these recognized math-style guides, besides maintaining an outdated tradition (just for the case the text before the formula happens to introduce the formula, which need not be the case, and even if so, a page break between intro and formula doesn't really hurt ***more*** than elsewhere, perhaps it even hurts ***less*** than elsewhere)? As for `\\*`, I'm afraid I don't quite get what you mean. Probably you're thinking of some combination of `\allowdisplaybreaks[1]`, `\\ `, `\\*`, and `\displaybreak[]`, but I cannot figure out now what would that be.

Comment: The math style guides are followed by publishers who still issue their publications on paper and want them to look good.  It is usually the case that a display *is* the continuation of the previous paragraph, in which case a page break is illogical.  But there is a syntax/logic error in the code you quote: penalties are *not* lengths, so `\setlength{\predisplaypenalty}{0}` should instead be `\predisplaypenalty 0`. (continued)

Comment: (cont.) To allow breaks within `align` and similar environments, add `\allowdisbreaks` and then end lines where a break should *not* occur with `\\*`.  (The vertical skip you've added in your example is too long to accommodate the `\vdots` on the first page.)  This has been tested.  I can add "corrected" code in an answer if you wish.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, corrected to `\predisplaypenalty=0`. As for the style, there is no doubt that a page break is bad, but that's not the point. Most page breaks are bad because they disturb the flow of reading and may distract the reader further by, e.g., making him/her turn over a page. The only question is whether breaking just before a block with a formula or formulas is worse than breaking the preceding paragraph or breaking the block of formulas itself.

Comment: @barbarabeeton  In my updated example, that's not the case: the colon is a semantical separator between natural language and formal stuff, and breaking right after the colon is clearly the first choice, not the last. In general, even if the colon is missing (“Let us consider the functions …”), breaking between the English part and the math part is still giving the reader a chance to pause and prepare himself/herself to eat (potentially harder) mathematics.

Comment: I admit to a built-in bias.  I was employed by a major math publisher with a more than 100-year history.  The stylistic preferences, although perhaps old fashioned, had been thoroughly tested by the time I was let loose on their composition, and were continually confirmed by experienced mathematician/author/educators.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Concerning the actual example, are you thinking of something like https://pastebin.com/qUfjf69r ?  I don't see the penalties in the log, but my hope is that after `\allowdisplaybreaks[1]`, every `\\ ` incurs a default positive penalty, that `\displaybreak[0]\\ ` incurs a zero penalty, and that (as you say) `\\*` incurs an infinite penalty. However, this is just my hope; my test could not confirm (or refute) every piece of that.

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way.  It's just the opposite -- allow all, but explicitly prohibit the ones you don't want.  (I'm looking at the file `amsmath.dtx`.)  You may be able to get what you prefer by forgetting about `\allowdisplaybreaks` and instead apply `\interdisplaylinepenalty=0` where you want to allow a break.  (Not guaranteed.  I'm editing a long TUGboat article, and am rather distracted.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm confused. Concerning “allow all, but explicitly prohibit the ones you don't want.”: That's exactly what I meant. In my understanding, `\allowdisplaybreaks[1]` allows all breaks at `\\ ` (with a positive penalty less than infinity?), and `\\*` prohibits the ones we don't want. The only question is how to get the zero penalty (i.e., neither discouraging nor encouraging a page break) at `\\ ` under these circumstances.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Perhaps, I was not clear. I extended my question post to clarify our needs for this MWE.